# Explain why there may not be $3$ people with same car.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle, ramsey-theory

I don't really understand how to apply Ramsey Theory or the Pigeonhole Principal, so I can't see why this is true:

There are $100$ people at a party.

Assume each person has an even number of cars, possibly zero but no more than $98$ (super rich people).

Can anyone explain why there **may not** be three people with the same number of cars?

Comment: You are leaving out details.  Suppose they all have no cars and there are no cars involved.  Or then all have 98 cars and there are 9,800 cars involved.  Those are both certainly possible.  I imagine there is some stipulation about how many total cars there are?

Comment: @fleablood : Most likely a translation problem.  How about "Can anyone explain how it could be that no three people have the same number of cars?"

Comment: Or do you mean why it is not possible for there to be *exactly* one group of $3$ people with the same number of cars but no other group of three people can have the same number of cars?

Comment: @fleablood Exactly what I was thinking, but that is not the answer, So I am confused as well.

Comment: It is possible for $3$ people to have the same number of cars. Let people $1,2,3$ have $0$ cars, and people $4,5$ have $2$ and $6,7$ have $4$, ..... and people $2k, 2k+1$ have $2(k-1)$... so people $8,9$ have $6$ and people $10,11$ have $8$ and so on.. up to $98,99$ have $96$ and person $100$ has $98$.   And it is possible for there *not* to be $3$ people with the same number: person $1,2$ con have zero, and people $3,4$ have $2$ and people $2k+1, 2k+2$ have $2k$. up to $97$ and $98$ have $96$ and $99$ and $100$ have $98$.

Comment: What *exactly* is the question.  Word for word.  After thought as it is possible for $3$ people to have the same number.  And it possible for *exactly* one group of $3$ or multiple groups of $3$ and it is also possible for *no* groups of $3$.... I figure Eric Towers interpretation must be the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

There are $50$ possible numbers of cars. If each number applies to $2$ people, that's $100$ people accounted for.